# Simple LWJGL program displays nothing

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I gave [Archsynthetics](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut)' primer and *Hello triangle* chapters a read and decided to jump in with LWJGL. When I didn't get anything on the screen after my first attempt, I tried again pretty much porting some C++ code over from another [GL 3.x tutorial](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Tutorial%3a_OpenGL_3.1_The_First_Triangle_%28C%2B%2B/Win%29), to no avail.

As far as I can tell, I have all of the parts together, yet the screen is still black. I understand the concepts, but I'm sure I'm missing something simple here.

I've cut this down as simply as I can. Note that the following class uses [this shader helper](http://lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=GLSL_Utility_Class), and from what I can tell it works as expected (other than lacking error checking - however, I've ensured the shaders compile).

```
public class HelloTriangle31 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws LWJGLException, InterruptedException, IOException
    {
        // Setup display mode (size)
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(800, 600));

        // Set context settings
        //  Basically forces 3.1
        ContextAttribs contextAttributes = new ContextAttribs(3, 2)
        .withForwardCompatible(true)
        .withProfileCompatibility(false)
        .withProfileCore(true);
        Display.create(new PixelFormat(), contextAttributes);
        Display.setResizable(false);
        Display.setVSyncEnabled(true);

        // Log some stuff
        System.out.println("OpenGL version: " + GL11.glGetString(GL11.GL_VERSION));     

        // Setup
    String vertexStr = readEntireFile(new File("vertex32.gl"));
    int vertexID = ShaderUtils.makeShader(vertexStr, GL20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    String fragStr = readEntireFile(new File("fragment32.gl"));
    int fragID = ShaderUtils.makeShader(fragStr, GL20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    int program = GL20.glCreateProgram();
        GL20.glAttachShader(program, vertexID);
        GL20.glAttachShader(program, fragID);
        GL20.glBindAttribLocation(program, 0, "in_Position");
        GL20.glBindAttribLocation(program, 1, "in_Color");
        GL20.glLinkProgram(program);

        FloatBuffer vertexFloats = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(9);
        assert(vertexFloats.capacity() == 9);
        vertexFloats.put(new float[]{
            -0.3f, 0.5f, 0f,
            -0.8f, -0.5f, 0f,
            0.2f, -0.5f, 0f
        });

        FloatBuffer colorFloats = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(9);
        assert(colorFloats.capacity() == 9);
        colorFloats.put(new float[]{
            1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
        });

        IntBuffer vertexArrayInts = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
        assert(vertexArrayInts.capacity() == 1);
        GL30.glGenVertexArrays(vertexArrayInts);
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayInts.get(0));

        IntBuffer vertexBufferInts = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(2);
        assert(vertexBufferInts.capacity() == 2);
        GL15.glGenBuffers(vertexBufferInts);

        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferInts.get(0));
        GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexFloats, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBufferInts.get(1));
        GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, colorFloats, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);

        GL11.glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);

        GL20.glUseProgram(program);

        // Main loop
        while(!Display.isCloseRequested())
        {
            GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            GL30.glBindVertexArray(vertexArrayInts.get(0));
            GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
            GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);

            Display.update();
        }

        Display.destroy();
    }

    private static String readEntireFile(File file) throws IOException
    {
        // Open input stream
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        try
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) file.length()];
            int len = fis.read(buffer);
            return new String(buffer, 0, len);
        }finally{
            if(fis != null) fis.close();
        }
    }
}
```

*vertex32.gl*:

```
#version 140

in  vec3 in_Position;
in  vec3 in_Color;
out vec3 ex_Color;

void main(void)
{
        gl_Position = vec4(in_Position, 1.0);
        ex_Color = in_Color;
}
```

*fragment32.gl*:

```
#version 140

precision highp float; // needed only for version 1.30

in  vec3 ex_Color;
out vec4 out_Color;

void main(void)
{
        out_Color = vec4(ex_Color,1.0);
}
```

I'm failing to see where I'm going wrong. No errors, the only output is the version string (which correctly shows OpenGL 3.2 - *yes*, I've tried with and without any sort of explicit context attributes).

Something that struck me as odd in all of the tutorials I followed was that no projection matrix was set up using, for example, `glOrtho`. I've had applications in LWJGL (that use GL 1.1 functionality) that work okay with `glOrtho`, but now that I'm trying to upgrade/re-base/refine my GL knowledge I'm back at square one.

What am I missing?

**EDIT:** Having the VM argument `-Dorg.lwjgl.util.Debug=true` defined yields:

```
[LWJGL] Initial mode: 1920 x 1080 x 32 @60Hz
[LWJGL] MemoryUtil Accessor: AccessorUnsafe
[LWJGL] GL_ARB_gpu_shader_fp64 was reported as available but an entry point is missing
[LWJGL] GL_ARB_shader_subroutine was reported as available but an entry point is missing
[LWJGL] GL_ARB_vertex_attrib_64bit was reported as available but an entry point is missing
OpenGL version: 3.2.0
```

Comment: "*needed only for version 1.30*" That's not needed for *any* version of desktop GL. In fact, in desktop GL, it does *nothing*.

Comment: @NicolBolas The shader was literally copied/pasted. Not my comment, heh.

Comment: Why are you copy-and-pasting a shader from a *different tutorial* than the one you say you're working from?

Comment: It was from the one I'm working on....

Comment: "working on", as in "writing" or as in "reading"?

Comment: Reading. I'll update the shader loading code; I bind the attribute locations (you're right, I missed that part of the tutorial), but still nothing.

Comment: I also added the link to the tutorial I'm using.

Comment: @qix did you solve this problem ?

Comment: @Mihir No I never did.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the part where you tell OpenGL that `in_Position` is attribute 0 and `in_Color` is attribute 1. The tutorial in question does that in-shader with `layout(location)` syntax.

If you can't, or won't, use that syntax, then you need to do it with [`glBindAttribLocation` calls](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glBindAttribLocation) *before* linking the shader.